# How can my regular expression be matched with an unwelcome string?

Tags: regex, linux, command-line, grep

First I would like to clarify the context of my question. I am to prove myself at an interview, and the interview simulates the real world and I can consult anybody, do anything, the expectation is that I am to come up with the right answer. I have solved a lot of stuff but with this one I am stuck, due to the fact that I am not very knowledgable with regular expressions, nor Linux command line. I am to solve this task:

> > Pretend you have been watching a log file with `tail -f`. Pipe that
> >     into a grep invocation that filters the tail input and only shows lines
> >     matching today's date in format 'YYYY-MM-DD ' at beginning of line (for
> >     any future "today"), and containing the string '[error.critical]' in any
> >     capitalization. Be careful of the details; the matching should be
> >     exactly as described here.

For this purpose I have created a file named log with this content for testing purposes:

> 2018-10-03 [erroR.critical]sadkhasdhaksd
>
> 2018-10-03 sadkhasdhaksd [error.critical]
>
> 2018-10-03 sadkhasdhaksd [error.noncritical]
>
> 2018-10-26 sadkhasdhaksd [error.critical]
>
> 2018-10-03 red alert [Error.critical]
>
> 2018-10-03 red alert error.critical red alert
>
> 2018-10-03 [error.critical]

I have come up with this solution:

```
tail -f log | grep -io "^$(date +"%Y-%m-%d")".*\\[error.critical\\]
```

However, they said they can imagine two kinds of strings which would wrongly match this regular expression. I realized the following problems:

- I did not enforce space after the date
- I did not write out correctly the result, as after `[error.critical]` the additional text should be outputted
- I probably made a mistake with the quote as well, not putting it to the end of the string

Again, I am not very knowledgeable with regular expressions or Linux command line. The current approach is

```
tail -f log | grep -io "^$(date +"%Y-%m-%d") .*\\[error.critical\\].*"
```

Where the problems I became aware of after careful consideration were all fixed. However, they said that the first regular expression I came up with here can match two types of strings which should not be in the result. I realized one of those types (without the space), but I do not know what is the other type of string which wrongly matches my regular expression. Can you tell me what kind of string would wrongly match the first regular expression, besides those which ommit the space after the date?

Comment: You should escape the dot. You may use `grep -io "^$(date +"%Y-%m-%d").*\[error\.critical]"`. See [this demo](https://ideone.com/JA9tSf).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use this `grep`:

```
tail -f log | grep -i "^$(date '+%Y-%m-%d') .*\[error\.critical]"
```

```
2018-10-03 [erroR.critical]sadkhasdhaksd
2018-10-03 sadkhasdhaksd [error.critical]
2018-10-03 red alert [Error.critical]
2018-10-03 [error.critical]
```

---

- This regex matches a space after today's date at the start.
- `.` should be escaped, otherwise it matches any character.
- There is no need to double escape `[` and `.` in BRE.
- Escaping `]` is optional
- `-o` option is used to extract matched text only so it can be avoided.

Comment: While the final `]` doesn't have to be escaped because the opening one has been escaped, I find it more clear to escape special characters no matter where they occur.

Comment: Thank you! The answer to my question is therefore that the other type of text which wrongly matches my command looks like 2018-10-03 [erroR,critical]sadkhasdhaksd, since . is the character wildcard.